# DeepLinking with RN Firebase Messaging / React Navigation from quit state not working

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

Expected Behavior: User gets a notification via Firebase -> User Taps on notification -> app opens up and goes to correct page.

Actual Behavior: When the user taps on the notification (while App is in quit state), the app opens up normally

I've gotten this to work for when the app is in the background, but not when the app is in the quit state (user has swiped it away). I don't know why this isn't working.

I'm using RN Firebase for the notifications, React Navigation for navigating

to start off with, here are the packages used

```
// client Package.json


"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.9",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^14.3.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.3.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "@trpc/client": "^9.16.0",
    "babel-plugin-inline-import": "^3.0.0",
    "native-base": "^3.0.7",
    "app-symlink-folder": "file:../common",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.4",
    "react-native": "0.66.1",
    "react-native-async-storage": "^0.0.1",
    "react-native-autogrow-textinput": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-drag-sort": "^2.4.4",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0-beta.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.36.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.12.0",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.15.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-swipe-button": "^1.3.7",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5",
    "zod": "3.19.0"
}
```

```
// backend package.json



"dependencies": {
        "@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js": "^3.3.8",
        "@trpc/client": "^9.16.0",
        "@trpc/server": "^9.16.0",
        "dotenv-safe": "^8.2.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "firebase-admin": "^11.0.1",
        "firebase-tools": "^11.8.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "morgan": "^1.10.0",
        "multer": "^1.4.4",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
        "pg": "^8.6.0",
        "pg-format": "^1.0.4",
        "app-symlinked-folder": "link:../common",
        "sharp": "^0.30.6",
        "shuffle-array": "^1.0.1",
        "twilio": "^3.71.1",
        "zod": "3.19.0"
    },
```

Here is the Notification Object being sent

```
// firebaseMessaging
const firebaseResults = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcm, {
            data: {
                type: "MESSAGE",
                url: 'myApp://app/screen1'
            } as notification.NotificationData,
            notification: {
                title: 'title',
                body: 'body'
            },
        },{
            contentAvailable: true
        });
```

Here's the app entry point

```
// index.js



import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import fcm from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import * as notificationTypes from 'app-symlink-folder/notification'
import { Linking } from 'react-native';

fcm().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async(message) => {
    const parsedData = notificationTypes.notificationData.parse(message.data);
    if (parsedData.url) {
      // ** Note ** this openURL method isn't working. Some console logs have shown that it's being reached when the user opens the notification from the quit state
      await Linking.openURL(parsedData.url)
    }
  })

const FakeApp = () => {
  useEffect(()=> {
    console.log('inside fake app')
  },[])
  return null
}

function HeadlessCheck({isHeadless}) {
  fcm().getIsHeadless().then((fcmHeadless)=> {
    console.log('headless status', isHeadless, fcmHeadless)
    if (isHeadless || fcmHeadless) return <FakeApp />

  })
  return <App />
}

// Note: I've found some SO and git threads suggesting to do this. I don't think it's really made any difference since I've been working on IOS. I think this is for Android.
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => HeadlessCheck);
```

App.tsx is mostly just containers and providers

```
// App.tsx
export default function App() {
   return (
      <Providers and containers>
         <RootNavigation />
      </ ...>
   )
}
```

Here is the root navigator, that handles directing everything

```
const RootNavigator = () => {


const config:LinkingOptions<RootStackParamList>['config'] = {
    screens: {
      CHAT: {
        path: `chat/:otherUserId/:channelId/`,
        parse: {
          otherUserId: (otherUserId:string) => `${otherUserId}`,
          channelId: (channelId:string) => `${channelId}`,
        }
      },
      APP: {
        path: 'app/',
        screens: {
          'SCREEN1': "screen1/",
          'SCREEN2': "screen2/"
        }
      },
      HOMEPAGE: HOMEPAGE,
      NOTFOUND: '*'
    }
  }
  // linking used for React Navigation deep linking
  const linking:LinkingOptions<RootStackParamList> = {
    // url scheme
    prefixes: ['myApp://'],
    config
  }



  useEffect(()=> {
    const unsubscribe = fcm().onNotificationOpenedApp((message) => {
      const parsedData = notificationTypes.notificationData.parse(message.data);
      if (parsedData.url) {
        Linking.openURL(parsedData.url)
      }
    })
    return unsubscribe
  },[])

  // app navigator
  const AppNavigator = () => {
     

useEffect(() => {

    // cleanup function for fcm
    const unsubscribeFCM = fcm().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {

      const parsedData = notificationTypes.notificationData.parse(
        remoteMessage.data,
      );
      // do stuff with parsedData
      return unsubscribeFCM
    });

    
    // set up permissions for fcm
    (async () => {
      fcm()
        .hasPermission()
        .then(status => {
          if (status !== fcm.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED) {
            fcm()
              .requestPermission()
              .catch(e => {
                // handle error
              });
          }
        });
    })();
    return unsubscribeFCM;
  }, []);

  return (
    

         <Tab.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name={SCREEN1} component={Screen1} />
            <Stack.Screen name={SCREEN2} component={Screen2} />
         </Tab.Navigator>
       )

  }

  return (
      <NavigationContainer 
         linking={linking}
         fallback={<FallBack />}
         ref={navigationRef} 
         onReady={persistantLoginThunk()}
      />
         <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name={HOMEPAGE} component={HomePage} />
            <Stack.Screen name={CHAT} component={Chat} />
            <Stack.Screen name={APP} component={AppNavigator} />
         </Stack.Navigator>
  )



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

> getInitialNotification: When the application is opened from a quit state.

> onNotificationOpenedApp: When the application is running, but in the background.

instead of *setBackgroundMessageHandler*

See https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/notifications#handling-interaction